# What is the thermal average of an operator in the limit as temperature goes to zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, many-body

The equation in the link below defines the thermal average of an operator in quantum field theory and in many-body physics. What is this quantity in the limit as temperature goes to zero and why? Note that the left and right limits might be different.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_quantum_field_theory

Comment: Its expectation in the ground state? That's what the thermal state becomes at zero temperature after all.

Comment: What do you mean by left and right limits? And why should "they" be different, whatever they are?